# How to provide proper request body to serialize Django Generic Foreign Key?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, postman

I have a generic model called 'Phone':

> (my_project/apps/phones/models.py)

```
class Phone(Model):
    owner_name = CharField(max_length=50)
    number = CharField(max_length=20)

    content_type = ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=CASCADE)
    object_id = PositiveIntegerField()
    phone_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I also have a model called 'Client':

> (my_project/apps/clients/models.py)

```
class Client(Model):
    employee = ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=CASCADE)
    title = CharField(max_length=50)

    phones = GenericRelation(Phone)
```

I also have a serializer for 'Client':

> (my_project/apps/clients/serializers.py)

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    employee_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Employee.objects.all(), source='employee', required=True)
    title = CharField(required=True)
```

I followed drf-documenation (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships), and as I understood I need to put custom class in the same file, so here is how my clients/serializers.py looks like:

> (my_project/apps/clients/serializers.py)

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    employee_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Employee.objects.all(), source='employee', required=True)
    title = CharField(required=True)

class PhoneObjectRelatedField(RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Client):
            serializer = ClientSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of phone_object')
        return serializer.data
```

For requests I am using PostMan, so here is my request to Create new Client with phone number:
[image]

But it does nothing, new Clients can be created successfully but they just don't contain any phone numbers, please help!

Comment: Good! but where did you used this `PhoneObjectRelatedField` ??
add at `ClientSerializer` the field phone
`phone = PhoneObjectRelatedField()`

Comment: I tried that, but in my views.py: 'serializers.is_valid()' returns False, and I actually had to put it like: phone = PhoneObjectRelatedField(queryset=Phone.objects.all) because django says that queryset is neccessary

Comment: Okay, try it and notify me with the result

Comment: I've added: phone = PhoneObjectRelatedField(queryset=Phone.objects.all()) in ClientSerializer and I've made request with postman like: phone.owner_name and phone.number but my views.py causes the trouble, serializer.is_valid() now returns = False ((

Comment: Ok what did you get, I didn't expose to this one before, so we're solving to gether , can we go to chat?

Comment: Yes that would be great !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165108/discussion-between-a-raouf-and-madi7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the related field to the serializer fields

```
class ClientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    id = IntegerField(read_only=True)
    employee_id = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Employee.objects.all(), source='employee', required=True)
    title = CharField(required=True)
    phone = PhoneObjectRelatedField()
```

#### update by @Madi7

`phone = PhoneObjectRelatedField(queryset=Phone.objects.all())`